# Overriding django admin pagination along with dynamic values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on a project, I have a requirement from my client he wants to implement a dynamic paginator in django admin panel. Requirement is when user input 10, ten record will display per page same for 20,30

is there any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [ModelAdmin.list_per_page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641951/django-admin-how-to-dynamically-set-list-per-page/71753245#71753245). The default is `100` but you can change it to whatever you like.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = User
    list_per_page = 5 # No of records per page 
admin.site.register(UserAdmin)
```

If you want to dynamically change it I'd assume you'd use an ajax with a `GET` for the page number otherwise you'd have to do a lot more and alter the default admin `template` used by django.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641951/django-admin-how-to-dynamically-set-list-per-page/71753245#71753245) approach if it helps you .

Comment: Thanks,I fount this helpful <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641951/django-admin-how-to-dynamically-set-list-per-page/71753245#71753245">this</a>